# Recursively populating __all__ in __init__.py

Tags: python, flask

I'm using the following code to populate `__all__` in my module's `__init__.py` and I was wandering if there was a more efficient way. Any ideas?

```
import fnmatch
import os

__all__ = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    root = root[os.path.dirname(__file__).__len__():]
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.py"):
        __all__.append(os.path.join(root, filename[:-3]))
```

Comment: If you want to export everything, do you really need `__all__`? The default behavior is to export everything if `__all__` is not defined.

Comment: @alexis True, but I'd like to be able to *exclude* some, so I'd like to populate `__all__` with everything, and then remove the ones I don't want to expose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be doing this: The default behaviour of `import` is quite flexible. If you don't want a module (or any other variable) to be automatically exported, give it a name that starts with `_` and python won't export it. That's the standard python way, and reinventing the wheel is considered unpythonic. Also, don't forget that other things besides modules may need exporting; once you set `__all__`, you'll need to find and export them as well.

Still, you ask how to best generate a list of your exportable modules.  Since you can't export what's not present, I'd just check what modules of your own are known to your main module:

```
basedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
for m in sys.modules:
    if m in locals() and not m.startswith('_'): # Only export regular names
        mod = locals()[m]
        if '__file__' in mod.__dict__  and mod.__file__.startswith(basedir):
            print m
```

`sys.modules` includes the names of every module that python has loaded, including many that have not been exported to your main module-- so we check if they're in `locals()`.

This is faster than scanning your filesystem, and more robust than assuming that every `.py` file in your directory tree will somehow end up as a top-level submodule. Naturally you should run this code near the end of your `__init__.py`, when everything has been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I work with a few complex packages that have sub-packages and sub-modules.  I like to control this on a module by module basis.  I use a simple package called `auto-all` which makes it easy (full disclosure - I am the author).

https://pypi.org/project/auto-all/

Here's an example:

```
from auto_all import start_all, end_all

# Define some internal stuff

start_all(globals())

# Define some external stuff

end_all(globals())
```

The reason I use this approach is mainly because of imports.  As mentioned by [alexis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699305/alexis), you can implicitly make things private by prefixing object names with an underscore, however this can get messy or just impractical for imported objects.  Consider the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
```

If this appears in your module then you will be implicitly making `SparkSession` available to be accessed from outside the module. The alternative is to prefix all imported items with underscores, for example:

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession as _SparkSession
```

This also isn't ideal, so manually managing `__all__` is the only way (I'm aware of) to manage what you make externally available.

You can easily do this by explicitly setting the contents of the `__all__` variable (which **is** the pythonic way), but this can become tedious when managing a large number of objects, and can also lead to issues if a developer adds a new object and doesn't expose it by adding to the `__all__` variable.  This type of thing can slip through code reviews.  Using simple helper functions to manage the variable contents makes this much easier.